# Primefaces dropdown not setting value

Tags: drop-down-menu, primefaces

I am trying to delete an image which belongs to an album.
I provide 2 drop downs, the first allows to select the album the second to select an image of the album. The first when changes sets the second. 
Then the remove button calls a remove method.
I have debugged it a number of times but the values are always null.
Do you know why? how can I make it work?
note: when I set the first drop down the value is present but after I set the second they both become null.

Thanks

```
 <h:form>
            <h:panelGrid>


                <h:outputLabel value="#{diaryMB.selectedAlbum}"/>


                <p:selectOneMenu
                    id="albums" value="#{diaryMB.selectedAlbum}" effect="drop">
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select An Album" itemValue="-1"  />  
                    <f:selectItems value="#{diaryMB.albums}" var="album"
                                   itemLabel="#{album}" itemValue="#{album}" />

  <p:ajax event="change" listener="#{diaryMB.updateImage()}" update="images"/> 

                </p:selectOneMenu>


                <h:outputLabel value="#{diaryMB.selectedImage}" />


                <p:selectOneMenu 
                        id="images" value="#{diaryMB.selectedImage}" effect="drop">
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select An Image" itemValue="-1" />  
                        <f:selectItems value="#{diaryMB.images}" var="image"
                                       itemLabel="#{image}" itemValue="#{image}" />
                </p:selectOneMenu>
               <p:commandButton id="removeImageButton" value="Remove" ajax="false" action="#{diaryMB.removeImage()}"/>

             </h:panelGrid>
        </h:form>





public String removeImage(){
    System.out.println("I am selected image:"+selectedImage);
    System.out.println("I am slected album "+selectedAlbum);
    if(selectedImage!=null && !selectedImage.equals("-1"))
    {diaryManager.removeImageFromAlbum(diaryOwner, selectedAlbum, selectedImage);
    return "Friends";}
    else
        return "Home";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be beacuase your managed bean is `RequestScoped` and is being recreated after every ajax request.  Try using `ViewScoped` or `SessionScoped` and see if the values remain.